# can we give internal or private DNS on the API destination on event bridge target on AWS

Tags: amazon-vpc, aws-event-bridge

For I have blocked on internal communication on was event bridge My application is deployed on the AWS ECS for each login it creates an event and sent these events details to another application is deployed on same AWS ECS. Here AWS official doc referred as API destination but it needs to expose my application to become publicly accessible how I avoid it?